# Using object in multiple nested angularjs directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a list of person objects. I have a directive for displaying some read only data about the person and nested inside it a directive that acts as the toolbar for actions on the person (delete, friend etc). When you click on the first directive a second nested directive shows up to for editing the person.

In the [simple example in plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h0UzrbarEgZlCmlX4ad3?p=preview) this works fine, but in actual life this gets really flimsy with fields not updating, or updating infinitely (editor has quite a few ngRepeats making things even weirder) etc.

It seems awkward that I have 3 isolated scopes and pass the the same object to all three, but on the other hand I need a lot of properties/methods of that object in all 3 directives so it makes sense to pass the whole object. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
app.directive('personCard', [function () {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'personcard.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            person: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.isOpen = false;

        scope.person.close = function(){
            scope.isOpen = false;  
        }

        scope.person.edit = function (){
            scope.isOpen = true;  
        }
    }
}]);

app.directive('personToolbar', [
  function () {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'personcardtoolbar.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            person: '=',
            close: '&',
            edit: '&'
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
}]);

app.directive('personEditor', [
  function () {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'personeditor.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            person: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
}]);
```

Comment: If your directives are always nested, then you don't need the isolate scope on all. The sub directives will inherit them. Also it would be good if you could provide a failing case, since it's not clear what kind of error you expect help with

Comment: It's not so much of a specific error, rather I am wondering if this is the correct way of going about it. I thought of inheriting the scope but the innermost directive (person Editor) is used on its own as well so I guess this one needs an isolated scope. The toolbar could inherit it. Is there a significant different if the 3 directives use isolated scope vs the same inherited scope for the particular object?